# numpy.float warning even though there are no numpy.float in my code

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run a script that uses numpy.float64 but when I run it the error 'module numpy has no attribute float' pops up even though the script does not use numpy.float. This error also blocks codes after calculate_tm30 for some reason. I have tried to downgrade numpy to 1.19.5 where numpy.float is supported without success and I'm wondering if there is anything I could do to solve this problem

```
 def __init__(self, verbosity=True, csv=True, name='Spectrometer'):
        """Initialize the object.

        Keyword Arguments:
        -----------------
        verbosity   -   option to hide/show different level of information in
                        console

        csv         -   specify if the object should create a csv file.

        name        -   device name.
        """
        self.logging = logging
        self.verbosity = verbosity
        self.name = name
        # opens the spectrometer for this program
        try:
            # creates a connection with the first available spectrometer
            self.spec = Spectrometer.from_serial_number("USB2+F04442")
            self.spec.open()
            print('SPECTROMETER CONNECTED')
            logging.info("SPECTROMETER CONNECTED")
        except Exception as e:
            self.spec = None
            print(e)
            print('SPECTRUM FAILED TO CONNECT')
            logging.info('SPECTRUM FAILED TO CONNECT')

def get_spectrum(self, log=True):
        """Get light spectrum from the spectrometer.

        This will override any existing intensity and wavelength data. This
        does not modify/affect any csv's or graphs created.
        """
        spectrum = [self.spec.wavelengths(), self.spec.intensities()]
        if self.verbosity:
            print('Captured Spectrum\n')
        if log:
            logging.info("Captured Spectrum")
        return spectrum

def calculate_tm30(self, spectrum):
        """Calculate TM-30 of a spectrum.

        Keyword Arguments:
        -----------------
        spectrum - Spectrum to use as the SPD (Spectral Power Distribution)
        """
        tm30 = lx.cri.spd_to_tm30_fast(np.array(spectrum, dtype=np.float64))
        return tm30.get('Rf')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = ATJSpec(True)
    try:
        spectrum = test.get_spectrum()
        print(f"{spectrum[0]} ||| {spectrum[1]}")
        print("Test result: ")
        print(test.calculate_tm30(spectrum))
        print("Test ran")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        time.sleep(1000)
        test.close()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\rrams\Desktop\ATJ\roboshi\ATJSpec.py:22: UserWarning: seabreeze.use has to be called before importing seabreeze.spectrometers
  seabreeze.use('cseabreeze')
SPECTROMETER CONNECTED
Captured Spectrum

[1.7698e+02 1.7736e+02 1.7775e+02 ... 8.8320e+02 8.8350e+02 8.8380e+02] ||| [1.6384e+01 2.7326e+04 5.7343e+02 ... 6.2492e+02 5.6173e+02 5.6173e+02]
Test result:
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

Comment: Try and change `np.float64` to `float`. See if the warning (not error) still occurs.

Comment: I tried and the error is still there

Comment: So then the warning likely originates from the `lx.cri.spd_to_tm30_fast` function, or a function called inside it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like an error; more "just" a warning. But the message "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'" should really result in an exception; code can't continue with non-existing attributes.

Comment: Oh, I see: that's because you catch all exceptions. Please remove the try-except-finally around the `test.calculate_tm30(spectrum)`. That will let the error bubble up, with a traceback, and you can see where the error actually originates from.

Comment: Be very careful with catching all types of exceptions. And let exceptions bubble up: if there is an error, you want it to be loud and clear. Here, you're showing the one-line error message, but no way to see where it originates. And next,  you ask yourself: "where does this error come from?" See the contradiction?

Comment: ^ More often than not, catching `Exception` is a code-smell. You should know _exactly_ what exceptions your code can produce, and handle those exceptions specifically.

Comment: That solved the issue, thank you very much.  This wasn't my code originally so I failed to catch that issue. I'll pay more attention to it next time